# Selenium: a pop-up window not showing up in window handles

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, popup, window

I am trying to get to a BibTeX entry of a research paper on Google Scholar using Selenium. For example, when one goes to [this](https://scholar.google.co.il/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Enhanced%20Partial%20Expansion%20%7BA%7D&btnG=&oq=enhanced%20) page, the top paper has the clickable quotes image below it. When one clicks the image, the citation window pops up. I would like to get the page source for that citation window using Selenium. However, I am not able to get to the pop-up window.

The relevant (at least that's how it seems) HTML element of the above page looks as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="gs_or_cit gs_nph" title="Cite" role="button" aria-controls="gs_cit" aria-haspopup="true"><svg viewBox="0 0 17 16" class="gs_or_svg"><path d="M1.5 3.5v5h2v.375L1.75 12.5h3L6.5 8.875V3.5zM9.5 3.5v5h2v.375L9.75 12.5h3L14.5 8.875V3.5z"/></svg></a>
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any'])
link = u'https://scholar.google.co.il/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Enhanced+Partial+Expansion+%7BA%7D&btnG=&oq=enhanced+'
driver.set_window_size(1124, 850) # Avoid the error of the element not being displayed, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11637
driver.get(link)
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('gs_or_cit') # 'gs_or_cit gs_nph' contains space and is not accepted. However, 'gs_or_cit' seems to work.
element.click()
time.sleep(5) # Enough time for sure for the citation window to appear
print len(driver.window_handles)
```

This code prints out 1. That is, there is only one window handle and the citation window's handle is not available. Why would that be the case and how can I get to that window and its page source?

Comment: The click displays a DOM container, not new window.

Comment: @FlorentB. Is that good news or bad ones? That is, is there a way to get to that thing's page source?

Comment: wait for the container `#gs_cit` to appear, and read the attribute `innerHTML`

Comment: It works when I wait by simply sleeping. If I try to actually wait for the element with the id `'gs_cit'` to appear, the wait exits immediately and the innerHTML attribute is `javascript:void(0)`. I also tried an implicit wait with the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a window, that's just a HTML dialog. You can treat it like any other HTML on the page and get its contents.

The parent element of that dialog is

```
<div id="gs_cit" class="gs_md_d gs_ttzi gs_vis" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="gs_cit-t" data-wfc="gs_cit-x" style="top: 253.5px;">
```

You can get it using the ID. You should wait for it to be visible and then get what contents you want from the dialog.

As to your code comment,

```
'gs_or_cit gs_nph' contains space and is not accepted. However, 'gs_or_cit' seems to work.
```

That is a compound class name ... meaning it contains more than one class. You can easily use a CSS selector, `.gs_or_cit.gs_nph` to find elements with those class names.

[CSS Selector guide](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)